# Why would a system of equations be solved this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If my instructions are to solve a system of equations using Gauss-Jordan elimination, and the matrix below is one of my final steps, why would I not be expected to fully row-reduce it to the second matrix shown here?
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&-1&0&1/2\\0&1&-2&1&1\\0&0&-6&0&0
\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0&1/2\\0&1&0&1&1\\0&0&1&0&0
\end{matrix}\right]$$

In other words, why would you write the solution (w,x,y,z) as (1/2+y,1+2y-z,y,z) which is what my book and calculator gave, rather than (1/2,1-z,0,z)  when y apparently must be equal to 0?  My only guess is for generality, but it seems to me that y must equal zero for the system to have a solution.  I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You have just encountered the difference between Row-Echelon Form (REF) and Reduced Row-Echelon Form (RREF).  The reasons that most people (myself included) don't perform the row operations to reach your second matrix from the first matrix are twofold:

1. The number of solutions to the system can already be ascertained from REF form.  I can tell (at a glance) how the remaining steps to reach RREF will change the matrix, so I can save time.  Often, one only cares *if* there's a solution, not necessarily what it is.
2. It is faster to backsubstitute than to continue row reducing.  That is, once you reach your first matrix, simply turn it back into a set of equations and use standard high school algebra techniques (substitution) for solving.

Comment: Wouldn't the act of back substitution cause it to degenerate into (1/2,1-z,0,z), because of the third row:   -6y=0.   That is what is confusing me most.

Comment: I have now found the arithmetic error that led to an "almost correct" matrix, my question is answered.